# Why is PHP PDO not pulling anything from my database (More specifically the UserPassword Column)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to pull the user's hash (saved under UserPassword) [Picture of UserPassword column in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvOxX.png)
and run it through password_verify(). The problem is, it doesn't return anything. Here's my code:
**HTML:**

```
   <div class="userInfo">
      <form method="post">
        <p>Username: </p>
        <input type="text" name="Username" required>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <input type="password" name="Password" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Log In"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $tblusername = $_POST['Username'];
      $tblpasswordU = $_POST['Password'];

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "mealplan";
      $password = "";
      
      try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mealplan", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = :tblusername");
        $stmt->bindParam(':tblusername', $tblusername);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        }else{
          die("Incorrect Username or Password");
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserPassword FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = :username");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $tblusername);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($tblpasswordU, $row['UserPassword']) == true) {
            echo "Signed in successfully";
        } else {
            die("Incorrect username or password");
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "<style>.hidden { visibility: visible; } .shown { visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px }</style>";
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Me echoing the Hash and Username were part of me testing. Here's the output: Incorrect Username or Password [] [123] (123 being my test user)

Quick note: $tblpasswordU is the unverified password the user put in.

Comment: `UserPassword` is a hashed password, it's not equal to `$hash`.

Comment: You need to retrieve the password by username, not by trying to match the password.

Comment: Above I already verified the uesrname, now I'm checking the passwords

Comment: `WHERE UserPassword = :tblpasswordH` is wrong, you need to select with the username. The hash is built with a dynamic salt and will never match again. The `password_verify` takes the salt from the hash and compares

Comment: @user3783243 so what would it be?

Comment: `where Username = ?` then bind the username/email

Comment: Why would you want to query a hash you already have? Moreover, you don't get any results from your query.

Comment: I need as an answer please

Comment: That is the answer. Select the hash by the username, not the hash.

Comment: But your code is confusing, and not everything is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password saved in the database is hashed, so you can't match it directly in the SQL. You need to fetch the password for the username. Then you use `password_verify()` to check whether the password the user entered hashes to the same thing.

Also, you have to fetch the row from the query.

There's no need to use two queries. Just use one query to test if the username exists and fetch the password.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $tblusername = $_POST['Username'];
    $tblpasswordU = $_POST['Password'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "mealplan";
    $password = "";
      
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mealplan", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserPassword FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = :tblusername");
        $stmt->bindParam(':tblusername', $tblusername);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!$row) { // This is just for debugging, in production you shouldn't distinguish wrong username and wrong password
            die("Username not found");
        }
        if ($row && password_verify($tblpasswordU, $row['UserPassword'])) {
            echo "Signed in successfully";
        } else {
            die("Incorrect username or password");
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "<style>.hidden { visibility: visible; } .shown { visibility: hidden; font-size: 0px }</style>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229422/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-why-is-php-pdo-not-pulling-anything-from-my-datab).